# Maximum number of acute triangles in a polygon convex

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, polygons

If $$ is a convex polygon and is divided into $ − 2$ triangles with diagonals. What is the maximum number of acute triangles you can have?

I did not understand the part of triangles with diagonals, but fortunately they helped me in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729637/maximum-number-of-acute-triangles-in-a-convex-polygon?noredirect=1#comment7668087_3729637), But no matter how much I look for how to solve the problem, it gets more complicated, mainly because of the factor of how to take the consideration that the angle is acute

Comment: Will it help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446438/how-many-triangles-can-be-formed-by-the-vertices-of-a-regular-polygon-of-n-sid/1446470#1446470 ?

Comment: I do not know if I am misunderstanding the question, but, could not the n-2 acute triangles be at first?

Comment: Is $P$ a regular n-gon or can it be any convex polygon with n sides?

Comment: The information only tells me that it is a simple polygon, not that it has to be regular. So I think it's any convex polygon with n sides

Comment: @Harish I have reviewed what you have attached to me and today I have been thinking.  I think the answer would be that the maximum of acute triangles is n-2 ?, based on what I have reviewed, it seems to me that it is the answer;  but I would really appreciate it if you correct me, thanks.